# Determine if a record is a descendant of another record using recursive CTE

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

The following table stores topics in an instruction manual.  Each topic has a parent topic except for record `id` of `1` which is the root.  The application allows all topics except for the root topic to have the parent changed, and I will need to prevent an ancestor from being assigned as a descendant of itself.

For instance, record #2's parent should not be changed from `1` to `7`.

How can I determine if a record is a descendant of another record?  I would prefer not to "hard code" the quantity of descendants.  Note that I am actually using mariaDB.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app`.`manual` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `content` TEXT NULL,
  `listorder` TINYINT NULL,
  `keywords` TEXT NULL,
  `display_list` TINYINT NULL,
  `parent_id` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_manual_manual1_idx` (`parent_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_manual_manual1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`)
    REFERENCES `app`.`manual` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

id   parent_id
1    null
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
7    6
```

Comment: This can be a difficult problem to solve with recursion. The more economical answer _might_ be a `path` column

Comment: @PhilippMaurer  Yes, there are answers, but they all seem to use stored procedures.  Is not recursion a better solution?

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @user1032531 Recursion is difficult in plain SQL.

Comment: @Barmar  Maybe so, but this seems to be a fairly common application with little deviation, and I expect others would benefit finding such an answer at Stackoverflow.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer  Reading up on CTE's right now.  Maybe I will get the bounty!  Oh yeah, it doesn't work that way :(

Comment: @user1032531 What's wrong with the answers at the linked question?

Comment: @user1032531 MySQL doesn't have CTEs.

Comment: @Barmar  I am sure nothing, however, CTE's exist and seem to me to be the right approach.  Note that I am using MariaDB as described by the original post.  I shouldn't not have tagged this MySQL, and remove it.

Comment: I don't follow the ` record #2's parent should not be changed from 1 to 7.`

Comment: Yes @Barmar MySQL 8.0+ has CTE’s but isnt production ready

Comment: @RaymondNijland Which is why I generally ignore it for now.

Comment: do you require a query which displays the results that you have listed above? id -> parent_id? and state whether the id is a child or not?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return a count greater than zero if record with `id` of 6 is a decedent of the record with `id` of 2.

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS (
SELECT * FROM manual WHERE id=2
UNION
SELECT m.*
FROM manual m
INNER JOIN ancestors a ON a.id=m.parent_id
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ancestors WHERE id=6;
```