# what is the best way to represent nested subcategories in relational database for say ecommercee store

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I have a category A, which have some sub categories a,b,c and in turn a,b,c can again have multiple subcategories.

I am thinking of have a lookup table having all categories along with their id(id name)

Another another table that will have map categories to its subcategories using their ids
1 > [1,2,3],
2 > [7,8,9]

Think of it as an ecommercee store,where we select a category and than it can have multiple subcategories and so on..

For this particular usecase  want to confirm if thats the correct relational design.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433253/determine-if-a-record-is-a-descendant-of-another-record-using-recursive-cte

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categories and sub-categories are the same entity **category**. Your entity has a relation with itself that you can express as:

```
category [parent] (0, n) - (0, 1) category [child]
```

> A **parent category** can have *0 to many* **child categories**.
> A **child category** can have *0 or 1* **parent category**.
>
> Of course, if a "child category" has no parent, it isn't really a *"child"* category.

This gives us the max cardinalities of **n** (many) on the left side (parent) and **1** on the right side (child).
A *"One To Many"* (or *"Many To One"*) relation implies to add a **foreign key** in the *child entity* (to the side where the max cardinality is **1**). As a *category* may not have a parent, this column will be nullable.

**Conclusion:** add a nullable column in your category table with a foreign key constraint on itself.

Your table could look like this:

| id | parent_id | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `NULL` | ... |
| 2 | `NULL` | ... |
| 3 | 1 | ... |
| 4 | 2 | ... |
| 5 | 2 | ... |
| 6 | 2 | ... |
| 7 | 3 | ... |
| 8 | 5 | ... |

Which gives the following category tree:

```
├──1
│  └──3
│     └──7
└──2
   ├──4
   ├──5
   │  └──8
   └──6
```